# C programming while loop

Tags: c

I was trying to show alternating series using `if` statement nested in a `while` loop.
That's the code.

```
main()
{
    printf( "Enter a number: " );
    int n1;
    scanf( " %d", n1 );
    int temp = 1;

    while( temp <= n1 )
    {
        if( temp % 2 == 0 )
        {
            printf(" %d", -1 * temp );
            temp++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf( " %d", temp );
            temp++;
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler does not show any error, but while the program is running it says that it stopped working. Any suggestions?

Comment: `scanf(" %d",n1);` is wrong. Increase the warning level of your compiler. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: @RSahu found an exact dupe.

Comment: This is no valid C code. `main` has no result type (should be `int`). YOu also should not have an empty parameter list. If there are no parameters, use `void`, e.g. `int main(void)`. Get a textbook which is not older than 28 years, best for C11 or at least the 19 year old C99. And enable and fix compiler warnings, a beginner should treat them as errors.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Since I do not return any values declaring int before main is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide `scanf()` with the address of the variable you are assigning to, use the address-of operator `&` :

```
scanf(" %d", &n1);
```

Comment: yes, but it's very basic duplicate answered many times already. and solved in comments before you answered.